# Export CSV in UTF-8 Java

Tags: java, csv, utf-8

I am trying to export a csv file in UTF-8 encoding so it can include foreign caracters (á é í ó ú) but when I export the file it doesn't work. This is an example of my code:

BufferedWriter bw;

```
    try {
        bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("./hello.csv"), "UTF-8"));            
        bw.write("decepción,función,torsión");
        bw.flush();
        bw.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
    }
```

If i export it to a txt file it works, if I change the extension to csv it ceases to work.

Comment: How did you test your csv file? Perhaps your csv file viewer doesn't display utf-8 correctly.

Comment: I think this may be related to file permissions, it is very strange as all files are seen as just descriptors when opening a file output stream... try creating the empty file and then opening a stream to it...

Comment: I am using excel to open the csv

Comment: If using Excel, go to the Data->Import External Data->Import Data menu item and make sure you select UTF-8 in the first step

Comment: define "doesn't work"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as the code goes, you are doing the right thing. And if it creates a txt properly then it should create a csv file also properly with UTF 8 encoding. Make sure you open in an editor that supports `UTF-8`. Try opening it in the same editor that you use to open the txt file.

Comment: I am using excel to open the CSV. I am saving this information as a CSV file because later I am uploading it to a database in Salesforce. I think its not the viewer because when I did an upsert in the database, characters were uploaded in ANSII not UTF-8

Comment: @Ricardo i believe excel can be a culprit. Have u tried opening ur csv in notepad ?

Comment: You are right, the culprit was excel. In the notepad it opened perfectly. I still don't know why when I upload the file to the Salesforce databse it still uses ANSII to insert/update characters.